# PHP works fine via browser, won't work via HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, php, httpwebrequest

### My goal

I'm trying to read and write files from my webserver via C#.

### Progress

So far, via PHP I made it to work that you can write to files with `file_put_contents()`. The saved files are text files, so you can easily read them. My C# program with responses works fine, and I get my desired values.

```
    private string GetWarnInfo(string id)
        {
            try
                {
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create($"http://example.com/{id}.txt");
                request.Method = "GET";

                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

100% of the time it did not return null, which is a success.

### The problem

Well, the writing. My PHP in `example.php` looks like this:

```
if (file_exists($_GET['id'] . '.txt'))
{
    unlink($_GET['id'] . '.txt');
    file_put_contents($_GET['id'] . '.txt', $_GET['info']);
} else {
    file_put_contents($_GET['id'] . '.txt', $_GET['info']);
}
```

While it fully works via browser calls (`http://example.com/example.php?id=23&info=w3`), and actually makes the text file, I can't get it to work with C#:

```
    public void ServerRequest(string id, string info)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://example.com/example.php?id=" + id + "&info=" + info);
        request.Method = "GET";
    }
```

For example, I call `ServerRequest((23).ToString(), "w3")`, but the file won't change, it will always be either non-existant or in it last state (if there was one).

What could cause this problem? How would I fix it?

Comment: You're never calling `request.GetResponse` in the `ServerRequest()` function.

Comment: I don't need the response, is it neccessary to get it? @Barmar

Comment: You need to call some method that tells it to send the request.

Comment: I thought `.Create()` sends it? Oh well, not very good with HTTP.

Comment: How can that send it? It can't send it until after you set `request.Method` on the next line.

Comment: You create the request, set all the options, then you call `GetResponse()` to send the request and receive the response.

Comment: It doesn't look like there's a method to send the request without receiving the response. Just call `GetResponse()` and ignore the result. Or if you don't want to wait for it, you could use `BeginGetResponse()` and provide a callback that does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Thanks to @Barmar*

I have figured out the problem, if I don't call `GetResponse()`, it will never start the web request. After doing that, everything worked fine!